# cant get info from for just by adding src

Tags: javascript

```
  success: function(d) 
        {
        for (var o in d) {
            alert(d[o]);
        }
```

this is part of ajax , i wanted to use "for" to get the info inside.

```
"img1":{"num":"1","src":"Img/House1/Image1.png",
"name":"Image1.png"},"img2":{"num":"2","src":"Img/House2/Image2.png",
"name":"Image2.png"},
```

and if i try to get the data using

```
alert(d[o].src);
```

it return undefined , how is that possible i cant get data just by using adding src ?

Comment: What do you mean by using adding src?

Answer (score 3):

Use `hasOwnProperty` and check for the value:

```
d = JSON.parse(d);
for (var o in d) {
  if (d.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
    alert(d[o].src);
  }
}
```

At most of the times, you might get `o` value as `length`, etc. And if you are definitely sure it is gonna be an array and not an object (i.e., not a named one), you can very well do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
  alert(d[i].src);
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
var data = {
  "img1": {
    "num": "1",
    "src": "Img/House1/Image1.png",
    "name": "Image1.png"
  },
  "img2": {
    "num": "2",
    "src": "Img/House2/Image2.png",
    "name": "Image2.png"
  }
}

;(function (d) {
  for (var o in d) {
    if (d.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
      alert(d[o].src);
    }
  }
})(data);
```

With the `for`:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "num": "1",
    "src": "Img/House1/Image1.png",
    "name": "Image1.png"
  },
  {
    "num": "2",
    "src": "Img/House2/Image2.png",
    "name": "Image2.png"
  }
]

;(function (d) {
  for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    alert(d[i].src);
  }
})(data);
```

Comment: i tryed to use f (d.hasOwnProperty(o)) before it still give me undefined.

Comment: Did the snippet work for you @Hacktor? Is this what the expected behaviour? Check in the console for issues.

Comment: this is the right way to get the data i know , but i tried your code i still have undefined , but i can get the d[o] , just not if i add the src.  even with the hasOwnProperty.

Comment: "img1":{ "num":"1","src":"Img/House1/Image1.png", "name":"Image1.png" },

Comment: with console.log(d[0])

Comment: @Hacktor Can you try `typeof d` in the `console`?

Comment: @Hacktor Should be this: Try adding `d = JSON.parse(d);` before you do anything with `d`.

Comment: if i add d = JSON.parse(d) , i cant even loop it. i checked the conolse , it said undefined token :

Comment: @Hacktor Why do you have double `"` all over?

Answer (score 2):

While iterating confirm that the object has that property, use **[`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)** method for that, For  more about dealing with object visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

```js
var d = {
  "img1": {
    "num": "1",
    "src": "Img/House1/Image1.png",
    "name": "Image1.png"
  },
  "img2": {
    "num": "2",
    "src": "Img/House2/Image2.png",
    "name": "Image2.png"
  }
}

for (var o in d) {
  if (d.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
    alert(d[o].src);
  }
}
```

Another possible method is using **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** and **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)**. **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)**  will retrieve all object keys as an array, after iterate over them then retrieve value using the key

```js
var d = {
  "img1": {
    "num": "1",
    "src": "Img/House1/Image1.png",
    "name": "Image1.png"
  },
  "img2": {
    "num": "2",
    "src": "Img/House2/Image2.png",
    "name": "Image2.png"
  }
}

Object.keys(d).forEach(function(o) {
  alert(d[o].src);
})
```

**Update :** Also check that you are added `dataType:'json'` in your ajax code, or parse json data in ajax success callback using `d = JSON.parse(d)` or `d = $.parseJSON(d)`

Comment: i tryed to use f (d.hasOwnProperty(o)) before it still give me undefined.

Comment: try `console.log(d[0])`, and what you get in console

Comment: "img1":{ "num":"1","src":"Img/House1/Image1.png", "name":"Image1.png" },

Comment: sorry I mean  `console.log(d[o])` not `console.log(d[0])`

Comment: "img1":{ "num":"1","src":"Img/House1/Image1.png", "name":"Image1.png" },
"img2":{ "num":"2","src":"Img/House1/Image2.jpg", "name":"Image2.jpg" },
"img3":{ "num":"3","src":"Img/House1/Image3.jpg", "name":"Image3.jpg" },

Comment: @Hacktor :  Also check that you are added dataType:'json' in your ajax code, or parse json data in ajax success callback using d = JSON.parse(d) or d = $.parseJSON(d)